# Buy 2 different SKU together get 10% discount on both items?

Tags: magento-1.9, price-rules

If been trying this for over 2 hours now in every possible way and I cannot get it to work.

I would like to have a discount of 20% when you buy two specific SKU. So for example when I order SKU 111 and SKU 222 together I get 20% only on these two items.

So if have further items in the cart it should only discount the SKU 111 and 222 nothing else. It works fine with one SKU but not with both. As soon as I have both SKU it just ignores the discount.

Here is what I have set up:
    CONDITIONS
    If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
      If an item is FOUND  in the cart with ALL  of these conditions true: 
        SKU  is  111
        SKU  is  222

and here:
    ACTIONS
    If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
      SKU  is  111
      SKU  is  222

as I said it works with one SKU but how do I combine that you have to have both SKU in the cart not just one of them.
Thanks for the help.

UPDATE:
I managed to get it to work like this but as soon as you have more than one pair it does not work.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**20 % OFF (certain SKUs)**

**ACTIONS**

The function we need to apply is “Percent of product price amount” and the discount amount is “20”.

The rule application logic we need here is:

If ALL of these conditions are TRUE:
SKU is one of [comma,delimted,sku,list]

Like the category list, we can also click the list graphic to choose multiple SKUs. Note that we need to use “is one of” in order for the rule to apply to any of the items in the list.

That should work then because the product has only one SKU and if you match these than that should be it.

**UPDATE**

The actions tab should only have the 20% and the rest should be in the logic.

```
If ALL of these conditions are TRUE : 

If an item is FOUND in the cart with ALL of these conditions true: SKU is 111 

If an item is FOUND in the cart with ALL of these conditions true: SKU is 222
```

Comment: Yes this works but as it says "is one of" it work also if I delete one SKU in the cart and then it just discounts the one SKU.
But the Discount should only work with both SKU in the cart.

Comment: Also tried "contains" and writting it this way
     If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
     SKU  is one of  111
     SKU  is one of  222
but then the discount does not work anymore

Comment: Yes but if the action tab says that all of these conditions are true and you have both of them there then that should work

Comment: Thanks for the update, but when I use the conditions you have in the conditions tab and only the 20% in the actions. Then it works fine if I only have those two items. But as soon as I add any other item it gives the discount on all other items aswell. But the discount should only be if you have SKU 111 and 222 in the cart and only on those two items. So its SKU 111 is 100 Euro and SKU 50 Euro then there should be a discount of 30,- even if I ad any other item.
Also if you add those two again then it should be 60,- discount. But only if I have those two together.

Comment: And if you say apply to products matching these conditions

Comment: I updated my question that you can see what I did now and it works fine as long as a customer only buys both SKU as a pair once.
The main problem is to figure out how to handle both SKUs as a pair. So if you buy SKU 111 1x and SKU 2x, to only get the discount once and if you order SKU 111 2x and SKU 2x then you get the discount twice. Also not getting the disount on any addition items you order.
I can't get this to work for me.

Comment: Oh ok now i get it. I am not 100% sure but i think that is not possible out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Working

If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
If an item is FOUND  in the cart with ALL  of these conditions true:
SKU  is  8908005256106

If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
If an item is FOUND  in the cart with ALL  of these conditions true:
SKU  is  testproduct

[image]